# Python to java image proccesing translation

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have some Python image processing code that uses Keras and TensorFlow Libs, which is needed to be converted to Java Framework.

My main problems are:

**a.** TensorFlow for java is not stable yet, so I have to find another  equivalent Java Lib.

**b.** I haven't found Java image processing library that covers the Keras image processing functions and utility (e.g. the class "ImageDataGenerator")

**c.** The program intends to be cross-platform for dummies (biologists....) so it shall not use any native parts that may cause realtime compiling problems for the clients, means it needs to be written in pure Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow themselves say:

> Caution: The TensorFlow Java API is not covered by the TensorFlow API
>   stability guarantees.

This however doesn't mean that your application will not be stable. The key take-away here is that whatever you will build is not guaranteed to work out of the box when new versions are released. However, if you pin down the version of the Tensorflow API that you use, you should be alright.